# Activity Feed plugin for website

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, feed, facebook-comments

I'm trying to get posts and comments from the companies Facebook to feed on the media page of the website. From the looks of what I read I placed this coding in the table cell on the site:

```
<div class="fb-activity" data-app-id="1413906032182585" data-site="facebook.com/negrilcafe" data-action="likes, recommends, posts, comments" data-width="434" data-height="561" data-colorscheme="light" data-header="true"></div>
```

and the following should've been placed right after `<body>`

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) 
 {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if (d.getElementById(id)) 
 return;
 js = d.createElement(s); 
 js.id = id; 
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=1413906032182585";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and now I'm getting a message once the site is live that  **"non recent activity to display"**

What am I missing?